# How do I implement check AD in ping script

Tags: excel, powershell

So a friend pulled this script to ping a hostname for me, and tell me if it is up or down. If the hostname is up, it will populate the IP address associated with it. I am no PS expert and would like to add a "check AD" feature and tell me if it is in AD with "Yes" or "No". Any help is greatly appreciated. current script is below.

```
$path = ".\results.xls"

$objExcel = new-object -comobject excel.application 

if (Test-Path $path) 
{ 
$objWorkbook = $objExcel.WorkBooks.Open($path) 
$objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1) 
}

else { 
$objWorkbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Add() 
$objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
}

$objExcel.Visible = $True

#########Add Header####

$objWorksheet.Cells.Item(1, 1) = "IP"
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item(1, 2) = "Result"
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item(1, 3) = "In DNS"

$ipaddresses = Get-Content .\iplist.txt

$row=2

$ipaddresses | foreach-object{
$ping = $null
$iname = $null
$ipaddresses = $_
$ping = Test-Connection $ipaddresses -Count 1 -ea silentlycontinue
$CheckDNS = try {$DNS = Resolve-DnsName -Identity $ipaddresses -ErrorAction Stop
    if ($DNS){"Yes"}else{throw}
}
catch {"No"}

$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,3) = $CheckDNS

if($ping){

$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,1) = $machine
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,2) = "UP"

$iname = $ping.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString

$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,3) = $iname

$row++}
else {

$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,1) = $machine
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,2) = "DOWN"

$row++}
}
```

I updated it like this.. It seems like it doesnt show me the IP address in cells A. But it will show me if it is UP or DOWN in cell B. But in cell C it will tell me NO if it is not in DNS, but im assuming if it is.. It will just show the IP address. I dont know where im going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this after the `Test-Connection` line in your script.

```
$checkAD = try {
    $comp = Get-ADComputer -Identity $machine -ErrorAction Stop
    if ($comp){"Yes"}else{throw}
}
catch {
    "No"
}
```

The variable `$checkAD` should have a `Yes` or `No` value. you can add this to your xls sheet like `$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,4) = $checkAD`

Your script could use some optimization but since it is ur first script, there is no need to write a perfect one. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. Im trying to better my skills in powershell. Whats the best resource for learning powershell?

Comment: In my experience, trying to learn it completely before writing it never works out. Probably because i m lazy and also the sheer amount of content overwhelms me. So I just start writing, getting some help where required, Researching only what i need. That gets me acquainted with the language and then i take the course. That's when things fall into the right place with me.

Comment: Ok so I need to throw another wrench into this... So to give some background. I need to verify if systems are ok to purge that match specific criteria. So the manual process I was doing was pinging the hostname, if the hostname didnt reply, then I nslookup, if that doesnt come back then I checked AD..

Comment: You can use `Resolve-DnsName` for that. Use a similar cobeblock as you used for AD. Please note that this `cmdlet` is from `DnsClient` Module. If its on ur system, very well. If not, you would have to install it

Comment: I updated it above.. and put the notes on the bottom. It still seems to not do what I need it to do.

Comment: Remove `-Identity` from the `Resolve-DnsName` line since that parameter doesn't exist for it. Also, if you are passing IP addresses to it, it would do a reverse lookup. Please note that reverse lookups can only be authoritative and not non-authoritative. Meaning, they wont resolve if the entries are not in your primary DNS server.